# Send command while expect can get specific text

Tags: expect

I Have one problem when i am using expect.
I need to list some information.
But the program list 10 items and then shows (More...) and waits a key
So:

```
expect "More..."
send "\n"
```

But the program shows more 10 lines and does it again, i can track how many times i need to do that, but the list changes a lot.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
while expect "More..." do
   send "\n"
done
```

I know the expect waits for a string, is there some kind of "hit" command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `exp_continue` and the block form of `expect`:

```
expect {
  "More..." {
    send "\n"
    exp_continue
  }
  "something else to expect for"
}
```