# How to send a command (to keep telnet session alive) while expect can get specific text?

Tags: expect

I have to save the output from a command from a 1980 telephony system (DMS100)in a file. I have an expect script to do this but my problem is the following:

1. This command could output information for as much as 10 hours.
2. For some reason after submitting my command my session gets closed after exactly 10 minutes.

I need something like this: [Send command while expect can get specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797697/send-command-while-expect-can-get-specific-text)

But the difference is that my expect can come true after 10-12 hours AND my session expires every 10 minutes.

I would like to send an invisible character while I expect for my string in order to keep my session alive. Something like this:

```
While expect "The End Of My Output"
{
send \007
}
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:

My problem was that the telnet port I was using was configured with a 10 minute timeout. Found another port without a timeout and its working correctly.

Comment: What's the point of sending an **invisible** char? Any special consideration? Usually to keep a telnet session alive we just press ENTER. :)

Comment: Well, the output is being saved into a file. Dont want to interrupt/deformat command output.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
# timeout after 5 minutes
set timeout 300

expect {
  "The End Of My Output" {
    # got all the output
  }
  timeout {
    send "\007"
    exp_continue
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Problem was that the telnet port I was using had a 10 minutes timeout. They gave me a new port and the problem was solved.